# ASP.NET Ignore exception for potentially dangerous request

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I've got an ASP.net webpage that allows the user to change their password. Currently, when a user creates a new password in the form field that ends with the "# sign" it throws the server error stating that a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client. I did some research and found that it's because it thinks it's a MySQL comment that is trying to ignore all code after the "# sign." For example, a user can enter a password such as ABC#& but not ABC&#.

Is there anything I can put in my code on my asp.net page, such as in the header line, etc. to prevent the server from thinking this is a SQL injection? All SQL in my code behind uses parameters so I am not worried about SQL injections at the moment. I just want every user to be able to have any combination of characters possible in their passwords. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: You should also be concerned with XSS (cross-site scripting). The type of warning you are receiving is intended to prevent a number of injection type of attacks. You can turn these types of restrictions off in your IDE (I'll have to research how to do so, as I don't recall off-hand); however, I discourage this as you are disabling a security precaution. I'll post an answer if I can figure out how to turn off the warning.  Oh and by the way, you wouldn't put anything on your ASP.Net page to circumvent this; rather, you'd need to disable this precaution in the code that the form is posting to.

Comment: This helps out a bunch, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this article from Microsoft if this is something you really want to achieve: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx

The article mentions you may have to modify your web.config to include the following settings:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

and

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Or for an individual page:

```
<@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

Note that these configurations may vary depending on the type of .Net project you are working on. The article I mentioned has more information. I strictly referenced that source.